# Difference between geodist() and dist() for Geo-Spacial Search

Tags: solr, geospatial, solr6

What is the Difference between **Geodist(sfield,x,y) and dist(2,x,y,a,b)** in Apache Solr for Geo-Spacial Searches ??

dist(2,x,y,0,0) :- calculates the **Euclidean distance** between (0,0) and (x,y) for each document. Return the Distance between two Vectors (points) in an n-dimensional space.

I was earlier using **geodist()** distance function for Geo-Spatial searches on my website but its response time was large. so have done a POC(proof of concept) for different distance functions and found that **dist(2,x,y,0,0)** distance function is relatively taking half of the time. But I want to know the reason behind this and the algorithms which both functions are using to calculate the distance.

I have to make a difference matrix for the same to convey it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that `geodist()` is intended to work with spatial field types.

Most spatial implementation are based on Lucene's Points API, which is a BKD Index. This field type is strictly limited to coordinates in lat/lon decimal degrees. Behind the scenes, latitude and longitude are indexed as separate numbers. Four main field types are available for spatial search :

- LatLonPointSpatialField
- LatLonType (now deprecated) and its non-geodetic twin PointType
- SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType (RPT for short), including RptWithGeometrySpatialField, a derivative
- BBoxField (for areas, 4 instances of another field type referred to by numberType)

In `geodist (sfield, x, y)`, *sfield* is a spatial field type that represents two points (lat,lon), so the direct equivalent using dist() would be to implement `dist (2, sfieldX, sfieldY, x, y)` with sfieldX and sfieldY being respectively the (lat,lon) coordinates of sfield.

Using `dist (power, a, b, ...)` you can't query a spatial field type. In order to perform the same spatial search, you would have to specify every point's dimension separately. It would require 2 indexed fields (or *values per field* at least) for 2 dimensions, 3 for 3d, and so on. That makes a huge difference because you would have to index every coordinates of each point separately.

Besides, you can also use `geodist()` as is with the `BBoxField` field type that indexes a single rectangle per document field and supports searching via a bounding box. To do the same with `dist()` you would have to compute the center point of the box to input each one of its coordinates as a function argument, so it would be too much hassle to yield the same result if you want to use an *area* as parameter.

Lastly, `LatLonPointSpatialField` for example does distance calculations based on [Haversine formula (Great Circle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), `BBoxField` does it a little faster because the rectangular shape is faster to compute. It's true that `dist()` may be even faster but remember that requires more field to be indexed, a lot of preprocess at query time to be able to yield the same calculated distance, and, as mentioned by Mats, it wouldn't take the earth' curvature into account.

Answer (score 2):

An euclidean distance doesn't account for the curvature of the earth. If you're *only* sorting by the distance, the behavior can be OK - but only if your hits are within a small geographical area (the value of a unit compared to meters greatly change when you're getting closer to the poles).

There's [an extensive and good answer that explains the difference between a Euclidean distance and a proper geographical distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58653/what-is-the-approximate-error-of-the-pythagorean-theorem-vs-haversine-formula-i) (usually calculated using haversine) available at the GIS Stack Exchange.

> Although at small scales any smooth surface looks like a plane, the accuracy of the Pythagorean formula depends on the coordinates used. When those coordinates are latitude and longitude on a sphere (or ellipsoid), we can expect that
>
> - Distances along lines of longitude will be reasonably accurate.
> - Distances along the Equator will be reasonably accurate.
> - All other distances will be erroneous, in rough proportion to the differences in latitude and longitude.