# How to index d dimensional vector in solr using geospatial search?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, 3d-model

I am trying to create a plugin for solr that will enable indexing 3d models. I will take 'screenshots' of each model from several different views and preprocess those images so they'll be represented in 1d vector.

I wanted to use lucene/solr Geospatial search for that purpose, as I saw there is an option to index a vector (larger than 2 dims) and search according to distance form the vector (according to location).

Unfortunately the documentation for this option disappeared last week and it isn't cached in google.

How can I index a location vector with dimension > 2?

The link for the documentation was here:
https://wiki.apache.org/solr

And I found it from here:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html#SpatialSearch-LatLonPointSpatialField

Comment: You can still access [the old wiki through the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190326201547/https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geospatial search is intended to work with n-dimension points (Lucene), but it seems the Solr implementation for dimensions higher than 2d [is not available](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11077).

You can still do 3d spatial search with Solr if you index one dimension vector/coordinate per field (use a double fieldType).

Then, in order to query and sort documents by distance from a given point, instead of using `geodist(sfield2D,x,y)`, you may use [`dist()`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/function-queries.html#dist-function) :

> Returns the distance between two vectors (points) in an n-dimensional
>   space. Takes in the power, plus two or more ValueSource instances and
>   calculates the distances between the two vectors.

To compute the euclidean distance between an arbitrary point (0,0,0) and the indexed points for each document, you would use :

```
dist(2, fieldx, fieldy, fieldz, 0, 0, 0)
```

See also :
- [Calculate distance in 3D space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42640/616080)
- [Distance Sorting or Boosting (Function Queries)](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/spatial-search.html#distance-sorting-or-boosting-function-queries)
- [Difference between geodist() and dist() for Geo-Spacial Search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47690131/2529954)